# I want accurate BLE scan timestamps

Tags: java, android, timestamp, location, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm making a ble scan app for my internship to collect some that about the ble protocol. The problem is in the end of the scan i need it to generate a csv file containing a list of device address, rssi, timestamps of when that device was detected and finally the location of my location when i located that device, 'cause i'm planning to use it in a moving car.

My problem is that i keep getting innacurate timestamps even if i change the phone i'm using. the timestamps are way off (2002, 2011) and I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

this is the code i'm using to see the time stamps:

```
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
                String deviceAddress = result.getDevice().getAddress();
                long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (mDeviceTimestamps.containsKey(deviceAddress)) {
                    // Ignore this scan result if we have seen this device within the last minute
                    if (timestamp - mDeviceTimestamps.get(deviceAddress) < 3000) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                mDeviceTimestamps.put(deviceAddress, timestamp);
                Log.d(TAG, "New Device: " + deviceAddress + ", " + result.getTimestampNanos()/1000);
                mScanResults.add(result);
                }
```

And this is the method I'm using to generate the CSV file.

`````
private void generateCsvFile(List<ScanResult> scanResults) {
        if (scanResults.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }


        // Create directory for CSV file
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        if (!((File) dir).exists()) {
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "generateCsvFile: failed to create directory");
                return;
            }
        }
        // Code for generating CSV file containing scan data
        // Use OpenCSV library or similar
        String filename = "scan_" + new Date().getTime() + ".csv";
        File file = new File(dir, filename);

        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
            CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(fileWriter);

            // Add header row to CSV file
            String[] headerRow = {"Device Name", "Device Address", "RSSI", "Timestamp", "Latitude", "Longitude"};
            csvWriter.writeNext(headerRow);
            String[] headerRow2 = {"Number of devices"};
            csvWriter.writeNext(headerRow2);

            // Add row for number of unique devices
            Set<String> uniqueDeviceAddresses = new HashSet<>();
            for (ScanResult result : scanResults) {
                uniqueDeviceAddresses.add(result.getDevice().getAddress());
            }
            String[] numUniqueDevicesRow = {"Number of Unique Devices:", String.valueOf(uniqueDeviceAddresses.size()), "", "", "", ""};
            csvWriter.writeNext(numUniqueDevicesRow);

            // Loop through scan results and write data to CSV file
            // Replace with your own list of ScanResult objects
            for (ScanResult result : scanResults) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_CONNECT_PERMISSION);
                    return;
                }
                String deviceName = result.getDevice().getName();
                if (deviceName == null) {
                    deviceName = "n/a";
                }
                String deviceAddress = result.getDevice().getAddress();
                int rssi = result.getRssi();
                long timestampMillis = result.getTimestampNanos() / 1000000; // Convert nanoseconds to milliseconds
                String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date(timestampMillis));

                // Find the most recent location update that occurred before the timestamp of this scan result
                Location loc = null;
                for (int i = mlocationUpdates.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    Location update = mlocationUpdates.get(i);
                    if (update.getTime() <= timestampMillis) {
                        loc = update;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                double lat = (loc != null) ? loc.getLatitude() : 0.0;
                double lon = (loc != null) ? loc.getLongitude() : 0.0;

                String[] row = {deviceName, deviceAddress, String.valueOf(rssi), timestamp, String.valueOf(lat), String.valueOf(lon)};
                csvWriter.writeNext(row);
            }

            // Close CSV writer and file writer
            csvWriter.close();
            fileWriter.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "CSV file generated successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error writing CSV file", e);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error writing CSV file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }````
`
`````

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add a sample of your csv file with the wrong timestamps as well as the timestamps you expected? Do you see the wrong timestamps in your csv or in your log?

Comment: What relevant observations can you make in your debugger?

Comment: Consider not using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` since they are poorly designed and long outdated.  Look into [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). If for older Android devices (before API level 26), then through desugaring.

Comment: Is this relevant? According to [ScanResult Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.bluetooth.le.scanresult?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13) `TimestampNanos` *Returns timestamp since boot when the scan record was observed.* Note: since boot, not since the epoch that a Java `Date` uses.